# Heavy load on the computer caused by repeated permutations

Tags: arrays, ruby, performance, permutation, memory-efficient

I'm having the following problem, I want to make every possible combination in an array of strings, and return only a specific combination of elements within the total amount of combinations.

The array looks something like this.

```
array = ['ab','bc','cd','de','bd','ae']
```

In this example, the input would be

```
source = 'a'   target = 'd'
```

And the code that I'm using right now to get the string I want is this.

```
(2..2).flat_map do |n|
  array.repeated_permutation(n).map(&:join).select do |string|
    string[0] == source && string[-1] == target && string[1..2].squeeze.size == n - 1
  end
end
```

The output would look something like this

```
['abbd']
```

What I want to make sure when I select the strings, is that the last letter of a string is the first one of the next.

Right now it works, but I'm encountering several issues,

1. With huge repeated permutations, 8 or above, the computer just freezes, it is unable to handle such a huge amount of combinations, so I need a different approach to reduce the load.
2. It is difficult to implement a selection procedure prior to the permutations to help reduce the load as it is after the repeated_permutations method is executed that the combinations are generated.

Comment: brute forcing it seems rather inefficient since at each step there seem to be only a small number of elements in your array that are eligible (eg the first once must start with a). Your second question is unclear to me

Comment: Hello Frederick, sorry for the second point. It is indeed very poorly written. I will edit it to make it clearer

Comment: Looks like a perfect use case for regexes!

Comment: What does "huge repeated permutations" mean?

Comment: @Nakilon, what I meant is that by calling the method repeated_permutations(8) or more on the array, it creates too many possibilities and they crash the computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I.

You can see that it is at first just an Enumerator (that never freezes your computer until you cast it to Array or iterate through it):

```
array.repeated_permutation(2)
=> #<Enumerator: ["ab", "bc", "cd", "de", "bd", "ae"]:repeated_permutation(2)>
```

And the `.map` converts is to Array. To avoid it you should either use the lazy block form:

```
array.repeated_permutation(2) do |a, b|
  break [a, b].join if a[0] == source && a[-1] == b[0] && b[1] == target
end
```

or better call `.find` on it, so it would return `nil` (that works like a `false` in condition statements) if can't find some:

```
array.repeated_permutation(2).find do |a, b|
  a[0] == source && a[-1] == b[0] && b[1] == target
end
```

### II.

I guess you want to find the path from one verticle to another in a graph.
I believe this was implemented in Ruby here a lot of times and you may have a look at the ["Optimizing breadth-first-search code" question on Codereview site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/65068/665)

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Nakilon, I find that it is slightly more useful than what I had before, but it still takes too long to load when looking at 8 or higher repeated permutations.

Comment: @Trismegisto, also note that sometimes these combinatoric methods from Ruby stdlib work better on sorted data: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/128788/665